# How can I check what version of netcat am I running?

Tags: netcat, version

`netcat` doesn't support `--version` or `--license` flag, running `strings` against the binary doesn't mention version number or anything of that kind. How can I reliably check what does version (openbsd/gnu + version number) does a particular `nc` binary implement?

Comment: `dpkg --list | grep netcat` could help, should at least show the package version

Answer (score 6):

For Debian, Ubuntu, and Mint:

```
netcat -h
nc -h
```

For Fedora, Red Hat Enterprise Linux, and CentOS:

```
ncat -h
```

The first line of those commands will give the version.

Comment: @StephenKitt  `netcat-openbsd 1.187-1ubuntu0.1` does show its version (atleast on ubuntu)

Comment: @Panki huh so it does, that’ll teach me to rely on (mis)understanding the source code instead of running the command...

Comment: ncat comes from nmap on RHEL and nc from nc.. these are two different packages/programs.

Comment: @olivierg No one made any claims to the contrary.